# Can't print bash output using subprocess.Popen

Tags: bash, python-2.7, subprocess

When trying to use subprocess.Popen I can't get the bash output and receive the following error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The code is:

```py
import subprocess

# Graphic-card

out = subprocess.Popen(['lspci', '|', 'grep', ''NVIDIA'''],

         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,

         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

stdout,stderr = out.communicate()

print(stdout)
```

Comment: There should be an error written to stderr (from `lspci` indicating that it doesn't recognize being called with `|`, `grep` and `NVIDIA` as arguments -- for the reason given in chepner's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is not a command argument; it's shell syntax that joins two commands. For this command, you need to either let the shell handle the pipe:

```
out = subprocess.Popen("lspci | grep NVIDIA", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or create two `Popen` instances and connect them yourself:

```
pre_out = subprocess.Popen(["lspci"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "NVIDIA"], stdin=pre_out.stdout, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Hi friend. That works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help and explanation!